# Application crashing during bootstrap

Tags: maven, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I'm trying to use the cf-mvn-plugin for app deployment to a cloudfoundary based infrastructure.

The application (that runs locally without any problems) immediately crashes. While bootstraping the logs look almost like on my local machine, only difference is that I get messages like this:

```
2015-12-07 10:39:04 [App/0] OUT 2015-12-07 09:39:04,691 INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Then at a certain time during bootstrap, the app crashes:

```
2015-12-07 10:42:41 [DEA/18] ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-12-07 10:42:41 [API/0] OUT App instance exited with guid 405d6d18-d730-4765-a98b-7f5986f87eb2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"405d6d18-d730-4765-a98b-7f5986f87eb2", "version"=>"6023f58c-9165-4a6d-8403-2727ec9f3723", "instance"=>"2118978ed1f54f18a03b1d77f82f3b58", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1449481361}
2015-12-07 10:42:41 [API/3] OUT App instance exited with guid 405d6d18-d730-4765-a98b-7f5986f87eb2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"405d6d18-d730-4765-a98b-7f5986f87eb2", "version"=>"6023f58c-9165-4a6d-8403-2727ec9f3723", "instance"=>"2118978ed1f54f18a03b1d77f82f3b58", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1449481361}
```

Here my current `cf-maven-plugin` config:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
                <artifactId>cf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>${cloudfoundry.server}</server>
                    <target>${cloudfoundry.target}</target>
                    <org>${cloudfoundry.org}</org>
                    <space>${cloudfoundry.space}</space>
                    <memory>1024</memory>
                    <appname>myApp</appname>
                    <url>my-app.scapp.io</url>
                    <healthCheckTimeout>180</healthCheckTimeout>
                    <appStartupTimeout>10</appStartupTimeout>
                    <env>
                        <JAVA_OPTS>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom</JAVA_OPTS>
                    </env>
                    <services>
                        <service>
                            <name>datadb</name>
                            <label>${cloudfoundry.service.datadb.label}</label>
                            <plan>${cloudfoundry.service.datadb.plan}</plan>
                        </service>
                    </services>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

CLI-Version: 6.14.0+2654a47-2015-11-18

cf-mvn-plugin version: 1.1.2

Thanks!

Comment: Your application takes too long to start up. The message you get is just informational and isn't related. Check your logs and/or increate the timeout for your application.

Comment: There is nothing special im my logs. How can I increase the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

When an app is deployed to CF, the platform will check the health of the app at startup and expect it to be running after a certain amount of time. In your case, you have configured this health check timeout to be 180 seconds (`<healthCheckTimeout>180</healthCheckTimeout>`). This is the maximum timeout the platform supports.

Since you have assigned a route to the app (with `<url>haufe-demo.scapp.io</url>`), the platform will access that URL and expect a response within the 3 minute timeout period. If the app is not a web app and does not respond to HTTP requests, then it should be deployed without a route. In the app has no route, the platform health check just ensures that the PID is alive.

The `[DEA/18] ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections` error indicates that your app was not accepting HTTP connections within the 3 minute timeout window.